# learn.fine_tune not showing progress bar for each epoch

Tags: fast-ai

For some reason, I am able to execute the cell but for some reason not able to see the progress bar while learning, any suggestions or pointers ? Screenshot shown below -

[image]
Ex. of what I am referring to is shown in the image below –

https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/02_production.ipynb

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I spent 2 days on this issue. The problem is not with fastai but with VS Code jupyter extension and it is an open issue currently. So there is a hack to get it done and I found it at fastai forum (Ref: https://forums.fast.ai/t/using-visual-studio-code-with-fastai-vscode-bug/77976/8), you need to add this code at the beginning of your code and the results will appear.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output, DisplayHandle
def update_patch(self, obj):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    self.display(obj)
DisplayHandle.update = update_patch
```

You can also run the code in python file and it'll work fine without the above mentioned code or in jupyter notebook which is not running on VS Code